# Can you delete cookies used by the installer user-agent (different from Safari) on an iOS mobile device?

Tags: ios, authentication, deployment, cookies, ota

We are deploying iOS apps over the air (OTA) within our enterprise to employees and we are controlling who can access the download site via SiteMinder which authenticates the user and authorizes them based on AD group membership.  This authentication process creates a cookie on the device indicating the user is authenticated (and probably that they are authorized too) so they don't continue to get prompted over and over again for each request.

The problem is that the user can download and install the app once and thereafter can never install the app again because they get caught in a credentials prompt loop.  This loop is caused by the fact that the Siteminder authentication cookie has expired and is not being deleted or renewed by the user-agent on the device.

From what I've read, this is because the OTA installation URL, which starts with "itms-Services://" uses a different user-agent than mobile-Safari on the device and doesn't respond to the cookie delete call from the site and doesn't delete the cookie on its own.  This also means that deleting cookies, purging cache and website data under Safari doesn't resolve the issue - Safari doesn't own the cookie.

Deleting the app (if its still installed) doesn't solve the problem either, nor does rebooting the device (I have not tried wiping the device yet and can't really start asking our users to do that anyway).

So, is there a way to tell the user-agent that itms-services is using to delete its cookies on the device or is there some other work-around to this issue for OTA deployment for iOS applications?

Using the Apple AppStore is not a viable solution in this case.
Changing the parameters in SiteMinder than govern the naming of the cookies so a new cookie is created is also not viable since this would adversely impact other single-sign-on users that this SiteMinder domain supports.

Answer (score 3):

We faced similar issue recently.  We were able to fix it by adding "Allow HEAD" to the protected resource in siteminder.  Siteminder admins may have only enabled "GET and POST" as allowed operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete cookies the following the way:

```
 for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

    if([[cookie domain] rangeOfString:@"mydomain.com"].location!=NSNotFound) {

        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how and where is this supposed to be run and will this affect cookie storage for the itms-services installer user-agent or just Safari managed cookies on the iOS device?  From what I'm reading, this may just be stove-piped and only affect cookies for the application running the code.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood exactly what you were trying to do. I think you'll have to configure your server differently to fix this. Can't you just make the cookies expire quickly?

Comment: That's the problem - the cookies expire and cannot be deleted to refreshed on the device so once you authenticate from an itms-services link for a particular domain, you can (lol) never do it again, apparently.  This is the problem I'm trying to fix.